# How to convert a complex object, having a HashMap parameter, into JSON and back?

Tags: json, hashmap, gson

In Java, I have the following `Toto` class, from which I would like to convert an object into a Json `String` and back into a `Toto` object.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class Toto {

    private HashMap<Tutu, Tata> tatas;
    private int id;

    public Toto(){
        tatas = new HashMap<Tutu, Tata>();
        Tutu tutu = new Tutu();
        Tata tata = new Tata();
        tatas.put(tutu, tata);
        id = 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Toto toto = new Toto();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(toto);
        System.out.println(json);
        Toto toto2 = gson.fromJson(json, Toto.class);
    }
}
```

With `Tata` and `Tutu` class:

```
public class Tata {

    private int id;

    public Tata(){
        id = 0;
    }
}

public class Tutu {

    private int id;

    public Tutu(){
        id = 0;
    }
}
```

However when I execute `Toto`'s main, I get the following print and error:

```
{"tatas":{"Tutu@b1bc7ed":{"id":0}},"id":0}
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 12 path $.tatas.
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:186)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:897)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:846)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
    at Toto.main(Toto.java:25)
```

I think the error is coming from the `HashMap` not converting well into the Json `String`, or at least not well enough to be able to reconstruct it afterwards. Indeed, the `Tutu` object is converted in a weird way compared to the `Tata` object right next to it. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: JSON only supports strings as JSON object member names. Could you please describe how you want your JSON data to look like? Depending on that there might be multiple ways to solve it using Gson.

Comment: @Marcono1234 Indeed, I can now transform into JSON my object with the enableComplexMapKeySerialization() method on GsonBuilder. This is a correct answer if you want to post it. Or maybe I should remove the post if it is a duplicate.

Comment: I think it might be better to close your question as duplicate (instead of deleting it). There is a "close" option below your question.